# Responsive Tabs with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that have a `v-tab` list of items and, in certain resolutions, it works great. However, I saw that when it gets lower than **`600px`** width, the tabs gets weird, they break a little and move off their space.

I'm thinking of displaying it in a vertical way for lower resolutions, however, I can't override the tabs style even putting everything with the !important attribute. I see that Vuetify has a prop called `vertical`, but, is it possible to use this kind of prop in a conditional way? Let's say, over **`600px`**, I don't want the `vertical` prop and under it, I want.

Can we make something like this in Vue?

Comment: yes, just like what @xonauga said in his answer

Comment: `breakpoint(value) { return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width < value }` if it's a custom breakpoint

Comment: if as you said around **`600px`** then it's already in Vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service scroll down to "conditional" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the `$vuetify` breakpoints feature is useful for you. Set the prop with a `computed` property depending on current `$vuetify` breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to use this kind of prop in a conditional way?

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
<v-tabs
   :vertical="$vuetify.breakpoint.mobile"
>
</v-tabs>
```

or:

```
<v-tabs
   :vertical="$vuetify.breakpoint.name === 'xs'"
>
</v-tabs>
```

More information here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service